# Remove ".so" files from dotnet publish

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm using **net core 2.1** and have a nuget dependency in my project that generates some ".so" files (linux binaries) under "/runtimes/linux-x64/native" folder, using this command :

```
dotnet publish --output Published_Folder -r rhel.7-x64
```

I would like to execute `dotnet publish` command but avoid this files to be generated, there is anyway to do it ?

**Important:** I can't change the `-r` parameter.

Comment: Why don't you just execute a custom cleanup script after the `dotnet publish`?

Comment: I can't execute any scripts or commands after "dotnet publish", this is a limitation inside our CI/CD. I need resolve this using arguments in dotnet publish or inside my application.

Comment: Then you can wrap `dotnet publish` in a custom script with multiple steps and call that script from CI/CD and not `dotnet publish` directly,, Can you do something like that?

Comment: Unhappy I can't change it.

Comment: This sounds like [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to publish your application, including all dependencies. Some of the dependencies are native binaries. Why do you want to remove some dependencies?

Comment: You can use the [`AfterPublish` target for doing steps post-publish](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/152). But I am still afraid you are trying to solve the wrong problem.